# Maven Failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

While developing a Rest Client project on Apple silicon Mac Book Pro with Eclipse, got this Maven error while updating the project:

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4
> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RestClient</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestClient</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

My JDK is zulu18.28.13-ca-jdk18.0.0-macosx_aarch64 and the build target is java 1.8.
Some suggested that this a firewall issue but I am on my home network so no specific firewall will block the traffic. The same project worked on my Windows computer but got the error when imported to my Mac Book Pro.

I also tried to manually create the project and then converting it to Maven project but still getting the same error.

My Eclipse is Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)

Anyone know the causes and how to fix this? I am not to familiar with the OpenJava/Apple silicon world.

Thanks

Comment: It seems Eclipse related problem. Please check the build in command line / terminal like `mvn clean install`

Comment: Nothing to do with Apple fyi

Comment: Thanks for the replyies Yes, I have nothing to do with apple. I found the issue. The jar plug in was not declared and it search for 2.4 so I think it may be too old? Add maven-jar-plugin with 3.3.0 and it worked.

Comment: Eclipse compiles incrementally when you save a file. This requires running some Maven plugins (e.g. those that generate code) and some that don't (like in your case). In your case, you get the message because that old version of maven-jar-plugin cannot be resolved, that actually nothing needs to be done.

Comment: I strongly recommend to remove this: `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` and follow the convention... also use `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` instead of using source/target and also using most recent version of plugins https://maven.apache.org/plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added maven-jar-plugin 3.3.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in my pom.xml on `<project`,  on hovering, got this error with many more jar's missing

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.22.0

I upgraded from

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
```

To

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
```

This worked for me.